# Can't connect to Minecraft server that I can SSH into just fine

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Me and my friends have a VPS located in Germany and we are all located in Iran. All of us can ssh into the server just fine and running `ping <ip>` returns very low latency responses (around 120 to 80 millisecond, given we live in Iran, is considered optimal).

However, when trying to host a Spigot 1.12.2 server none of us are able to smoothly play the game.

I, simply cannot join the world, I would be stuck in "Logging in..." and after a few seconds would be kicked out, then the console would just print that my IP has attempted to connect and timed out.

One of my friends can connect, but his ping is very inconsistent (from basically frozen to 600ms) and I also would have the same situation as him if I use a VPN located in Germany.

Things we have tried:

- Changing DNS servers (didn't help in the slightest)
- Using v2ray proxies (yielded different results for us, for me nothing would be changed and for my friends it would work but with very high ping)
- Changing server port
- Using an older version of Minecraft (spigot 1.10.2)

Is there a solution to this problem, or would we have to put up with since we live in Iran?

Edit 1: People mentioned usage of other server software, and having tried that yielded same results again.

Edit 2: also tried 1.19.3, same result

Comment: If the same problem occurs with vanilla Minecraft we can help, but we've decided that troubleshooting missed Minecraft is too much ..trouble, because there are so many additional parameters and ambiguities at play.

Comment: Modded* minecraft

Comment: it happens in Spigot 1.12.2 and Spigot 1.10.2. what other version and server software do you recommend me to try?

Comment: UPDATE: the problem remains using vanilla 1.12.2

Comment: im gonna try 1.19.3 just to be safe its not because of using an ancient version of the game

Comment: i tried it and it had the same result

Comment: Is the server's port open? You might need to port-forward 25565 on the VPS to allow you to connect smoothly.

Comment: just portforwarded it to another port, same result

Comment: You should try measuring the bandwidth between the server and client via iperf